# Reverse String C

Tags: c, string, reverse

I'm trying to create a program that reads text from a file that was previously created, inverts it, and writes to another file. The code I have now allows me to invert single words, but stops whenever there is a space or a paragraph. I could use some help in overcoming this problem. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int c, d;
  FILE *fich1, *fich2;
  char string [100], *inicio, *fim, tempo;

  fich1 = fopen("FicheiroInicial.txt", "rt");
  if (fich1 == NULL)
    {
      printf ("Erro - Nao foi possivel abrir o ficheiro\n");
      return (-1);
    }
  fscanf (fich1, "%s", string);
  fclose (fich1);
  inicio = string;
  fim = inicio + strlen(string) - 1;

  while (fim > inicio)
    {
      tempo = *inicio;
      *inicio = *fim;
      *fim = tempo;

      ++inicio;
      --fim;
    }  

  fich2 = fopen("FicheiroFinal.txt", "wt");
  fprintf (fich2, "%s", string);
  fclose (fich2);
  printf ("%s", string);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `fgets` instead of `fscanf`.

Comment: Thanks! I used fgets instead of fscanf and I can now invert whole lines of text, even with spaces. I still have the same problem when a line ends in the file though. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your current problem? Do you want the last byte of the file to appear first, and the first last? If so, you need to either read the whole file into memory, reverse the whole block of memory, and write it out to the destination (good for file sizes up to a couple of gigabytes), or you need to read the file in chunks from the end: seek to an appropriate offset from the end, read the chunk, reverse it, write the reversed data, and repeat.

Comment: ObNote: if you are going to put your code up for an international audience, consider using English words for variables. This would make your code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I believe fscanf() will only give you a word at a time. you will need to iterate over it until it returns EOF (end of file)