# Reverse file text

Tags: c, string, file

I'm trying to make a program that uses fgets to take the text from a preexisting file, invert it and then write it to another file. This is the code I've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int c, d;
  FILE *file1, *file2;
  char string [100], *begin, *end, temp;

  file1 = fopen("StartingFile.txt", "rt");
  if (file1 == NULL)
    {
      printf ("Error - Couldn't open file\n");
      return (-1);
    }

  fgets(string, 100, file1);

  fclose (file1);
  begin = string;
  end = begin + strlen(string) - 1;

  while (end > begin)
    {
      temp = *begin;
      *begin = *end;
      *end = temp;

      ++begin;
      --end;
    }  

  file2 = fopen("FinalFile.txt", "wt");
  fprintf (file2, "%s", string);
  fclose (file2);
  printf ("%s\n", string);

  return 0;
}
```

It works fine if the text in the preexisting file is all in one line, but if it has more than one line, only the first one is inverted and written to the new file. I think that fgets can only read one line, so I think I'll have to use a loop, but I'm having trouble implementing it. Can someone give me a hand? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're limiting it to 100 `chars`, that's most likely the issue. You can try determining the first file's size then dynamically allocate a char pointer to fit it all in.

Comment: Are you the same person who asked [Reverse String C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032262/reverse-string-c) because it sure looks like a translation of the code from there.  Personally, I don't worry about seeing code with non-English names and strings — I do find Japanese or Chinese ideographs difficult to read, but anything in Latin1 is OK.

Answer (score 0):

To read each line separately from file use `fgets` in `while` loop as below,

```
while(fgets(string, sizeof(string), file1) != NULL)
{
...
}
fclose(file1);
```

Inside the loop operate on each line to reverse it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand that. Using the loop makes sense to me, but how do I operate on each line?

Comment: @user3002222 Each iteration gives you a new line into buffer pointed by `string` which you need to operate on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has quite a few logical errors in it. I would recommend using other f* methods instead.

If you want an easy solution, open the file, determine its length, create two buffers of the size of the file, fill the first buffer with the file's contents and then do a loop to copy the reverse to the other buffer, then write that buffer back. Roughly that would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("StartingFile.txt", "rt");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error - Couldn't open file\n");
        return (-1);
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); // move file pointer to end of file
    long size = ftell(file); // file pointer position == character count in file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);  // move back to beginning of file

    char* buffer = malloc(size * sizeof(char));

    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), size, file) // read file contents to buffer

    for(long i = 0; i < size/2; ++i)
    {
        buffer[i] = buffer[size-i-1];
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); // The fread set the file pointer to the end so we need to put it to the front again.

    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), size, file); // Write reverted content

    delete buffer;


    fclose (file);
}
```

I haven't tested it and it may contain a few errors since I haven't programmed in C for some time. The only reason to still be programming in C anyways is efficiency and if you want your program to be efficient, the two buffer solution isn't the best either. At least not in terms of memory usage.

I highly recommend getting familiar with all the functions available in C (stdio and so on) cplusplus.com is a great reference for that.

Regards, Xaser

Comment: `char* original = new char[size];` is an arror in C. Maybe you are confused by C++ ? Also: the rev loop by the OP is correct: it _swaps_ using two pointers, that meet in the middle.

Comment: yes thanks, I have corrected it to using malloc, I hope it works now. You are right about the loop as well, I didn't think it completely through, i have also adapted the loop to reflect this.